# Read line BASH (Output $line and line below)

Tags: linux, bash, readline

I have a question to this read line. I have in my file n lines. How can I store the value in the line below in the same loop step? Can maybe someone help me with that?

Thank you

Details:

```
$ cat testfile.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

```
while read line; do echo "Current line read: $line"; echo "Line below: `grep -A 1 $line testfile.txt`"; done < testfile.txt
```

```
Current line read: 1
Line below: 1
2
--
10
Current line read: 2
Line below: 2
3
Current line read: 3
Line below: 3
4
Current line read: 4
Line below: 4
5
Current line read: 5
Line below: 5
6
Current line read: 6
Line below: 6
7
Current line read: 7
Line below: 7
8
Current line read: 8
Line below: 8
9
Current line read: 9
Line below: 9
10
Current line read: 10
Line below: 10
#
```

`grep -A 1 6 testfile.txt
6
7`

`grep -A 1 6 testfile.txt | grep -v 6
7`

Comment: Not at all, and do not use grep within a loop for this. Better use a string variable acting as one-line buffer to hold the value of the line before and turn your algorithm around.

Comment: Thank you, for your help. Can you make an example of it? I tried to make a variable within the loop, but without the grep, I do not see the way to get this value for this variable.

Comment: What output do you actually want? 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, 3 and 4, etc. or 1 and 2, then 3 and 4, 5 and 6 and so on? What are you going to do with the lines after?

Comment: I read these variables out from a temporary file. These different values are used aftewards in a sed, where I output exactly the information between these values from the original file.

Comment: ... but you are right steeldriver. When I read your question, and the thing I actually want/must do, then it should do 1 and 2, then 3 and 4, then 5 and 6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that you invoke `grep` for each line. In fact, grep parses each line, too. So, for a file with n lines, these lines are parsed n^2 times, and loading `grep` is quite an expensive call.

Use a one-line buffer, in this example called `PrevLine`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CurLine=''
isFirstLine=true
while IFS='' read -r LineBelow; do
  if $isFirstLine; then
    echo "This is the first line, so no previous."
  else
    echo "Current line read: ${CurLine}"
    echo "Line below: ${LineBelow}"
  fi
  CurLine="${LineBelow}"
  isFirstLine=false
done <"$1"
```

In fact, assigning `true` to `isFirstLine` is a string assignment, and just mentioning `$isFirstLine` (in the if-condition) is the execution of the command of this string. Since `true` and `false` are bash-builtins, they can be used directly without significant speed impact, but with a high increase of readability.

The last line mentions `$1` as input file name, so invoke with:

```
./test.sh inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your valid answer. Much appreciated. It definetly shows the direction to go. Can you let me know, how to make it the other way around - first line and then the other line. $ ./test.sh testfile.txt
Current line: 1
This is the first line, so no previous.
Current line: 2
Previous line: 1
Current line: 3
Previous line: 2
Current line: 4
Previous line: 3
...

Comment: So, the output should look as you want it now.

Comment: Again, thank you for your code rexkogitans. It showed how to output two values within the read line. As steelsdriver asked a bit deeper, I told there, that I actually use the values to do later on a sed on another file, where I then extract the content. So, 1 would be the value from and 2 the value unil incl. This means, that I need to have the values in pairs. There are always even numbers in the file, where I read the values out, to build afterwards the sed. I still need to investigate, but your solution helped me further.

Comment: Rexkogitans - I accepted your answer. I could start from it and do my changes. But it showed as always, that the requirements must be more clear before coding any character. Else it starts in a direction, which can be very expensive. The question from steeldriver was a valid statement. But thanks for your help.